# Win10: Annoying back snapping of the scroll slider

Tags: windows-10, mouse, scrollbar, snap

When I’m working in a window of File Explorer or a random application and I want to scroll up/down or left/right in this window with the mouse, the scroll slider snaps back to the starting position when I move the mouse pointer beyond a certain distance of the slider.
[See this example.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b81ryIXstuM)

Why is that? It’s quite annoying.
In macOS I can move the mouse pointer wherever I want on the screen without this snapping of the scroll slider.

I'm not the only one with this annoyance. See example 1 to 5.
[1](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/jtahh0/how_to_stop_scrollbar_snapback_in_windows_10/)
[2](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=27306)
[3](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/55623/why-do-scrollbars-revert-to-original-scroll-distance-when-mouse-is-dragged-sidew)
[4](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/scroll-snap-back-when-moving-mouse-away/2699)
[5](https://www.osnews.com/story/22601/windows-scrolling-behaviour-really-really-annoying/)

These examples show that this issue is quite old.
You see in the 5th example that the UI of Windows draws an invisible square around the scroll bar area. This area contains a fixed amount of pixels. When the mouse pointer leaves this area while dragging the scroll slider the back snapping occurs.

I've worked many years on a 22" screen with 1680 x 1050 pixels. Now I use a 27" QHD monitor containing 2560 x 1440 pixels. Since the pixels on the new monitor are smaller, the 'safe area' around the scroll bar is also smaller. I noticed that the back snapping occurs far more often than on the 22" screen.

I know it is possible in Windows 10 to drag the scroll slider without this back snapping, because the scroll slider of a random Windows Settings window proves this. For example: Press Win + I and choose Apps. No snapping of the scroll slider!

I cannot find in Windows Settings an option to 'unsnap' the scroll slider. (Maybe my request must be altered in the Registry.)

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: If you can keep the mouse within the bounds of the scroll bar, it should not do that. Have you tried a different mouse?

Comment: It also may depend on how far away from the scroll bar you get with the mouse. My mouse continues to scroll within about 5 mm or so of the scroll bar.

Comment: This is not a mouse issue and this will occur with every pointing device.
I’m aware of the fact that the boundry box around the scroll bar is the place where no back snapping occurs. But in practice it happens that the pointer sometimes leaves this area.

Comment: @sgrhill, *Please accept my apology* for the wrong information in the Answer, which is being withdrawn.. Those Registry changes *do* affect drag-drop, e.g., when moving text, but *not* the release distance for the cursor to scrollbar. Apparently, this issue is acknowledged, e.g. https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/55623/why-do-scrollbars-revert-to-original-scroll-distance-when-mouse-is-dragged-sidew

Comment: That’s alright!
So there is no registry setting to alter this ‘safe area’ around the scroll bar?
The backsnapping of the scroll slider is already present in Windows XP. Since I work with Windows ánd macOS I realize how nice it is to work without slider backsnapping.
I’ve posted this issue on several fora, even on the Microsoft forum. The amount of reactions on these communities are none to very sparse! It looks like the backsnapping is generally accepted by the Windows users. 
Do you know if the are fora where I can try my luck for better results?